# How to reshape a blob in Caffe?

Tags: neural-network, reshape, deep-learning, caffe

How to reshape a blob of the shape `N x C x H x W` to `N x 1 x (C*H) x W` in Caffe?

I want to make a convolution layer the weights of which are identical between channels.

One way I come up with is to reshape the bottom blob of the shape `N x C x H x W` to `N x 1 x (C*H) x W` and place a convolution layer upon it. But I just don't know how to reshape a blob.

Please help me out, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

As pointed by [whjxnyzh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35005464/1714410), you can use `"Reshape"` layer. Caffe is quite flexible in the way it allows you to define the output shape.
See [the declaration of `reshap_param` in caffe.proto`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L899):

> ```
> // Specify the output dimensions. If some of the dimensions are set to 0,
> // the corresponding dimension from the bottom layer is used (unchanged).
> // Exactly one dimension may be set to -1, in which case its value is
> // inferred from the count of the bottom blob and the remaining dimensions.
> ```

In your case I guess you'll have a layer like this:

```
layer {
  name: "my_reshape"
  type: "Reshape"
  bottom: "in"
  top: "reshaped_in"
  reshape_param { shape: {dim: 0 dim: 1 dim: -1 dim: 0 } }
}
```

See also on [caffe.help](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/reshape.html).

Comment: Can this also be accomplished by blob's class method `reshape(const vector<int>& shape)` ?   What's the difference between class method `reshape` and the reshape layer?

Answer (score 2):

Caffe now has a reshapeLayer for you.
http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1ReshapeLayer.html

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your final objective right, Caffe's convolution layer already can do multiple input-output convolution with common/shared filters like:

```
layer {
  name:   "conv"
  type:   "Convolution"
  bottom: "in1"
  bottom: "in2"
  bottom: "in3"
  top:    "out1"
  top:    "out2"
  top:    "out3"
  convolution_param {
    num_output : 10  #the same 10 filters for all 3 inputs
    kernel_size: 3        
  }
}
```

Assuming you have all streams split (slice layer can do that), and finally you may merge them if desired with a concat or eltwise layer.

That avoid the needs of reshaping blob, convolved, and then reshaping it back, which might introduce cross-channel interference near the margins.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this fits your specs exactly, but Caffe does have flattening layers. The blob goes from n * c * h * w to n * (c*h*w) * 1 * 1.

See http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers.html